# Method extracting out of android actvity and placing it in a class of the packet? What could go wrong?

Tags: java, android

Hello brilliant people!

So, I have this activity which uses some made-by-me methods, which methods of course contain other methods and those other methods happen to be part of the android.*; package.

Nothing weird so far....

I intend to embrace modularity for the sake of Java and to make my code beautiful, so I think why not extracting my methods into some other class, which is not an Activity child, is just a vessel to contain static methods which I can call from my activity....

To be more exact, that´s my method:

```
// This function reads a txt file is my MATLAB vector and converts it
// into an Integer[] array for use by the plot function
public Integer[] convertFiletoIntegerArray(int id)
        throws NotFoundException, NumberFormatException {

    List<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in));

    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        vector.add(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
    }

    Integer[] splVector = vector.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    return splVector;
}
```

I take this piece of code and crop-paste in my Methods.java class...

Well at the beginning I declare my method as static but keep getting this error:

```
line 81: InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);

error: The method getResources() is undefined for the type Methods
```

It is under my consideration that the `getResources()` method cannot be used inside a class that is not an `Activity` or something....

I don't really know how to solve this issue and once again I seek help..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method needs access to a context or to the resources. You have two options:

1. Pass a context as an argument to the method
2. Pass a context to the `Methods` constructor and save it as a member field.

I recommend the first because, depending on how your code is structured, the second may leak memory if the the activity is destroyed and re-created (say, due to a device reorientation). The first method has the added benefit of allowing the method to be static.

```
public static Integer[] convertFiletoIntegerArray(int id, Context activity)
        throws NotFoundException, NumberFormatException {

    List<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    InputStream in = activity.getResources().openRawResource(id);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in));

    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        vector.add(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
    }

    Integer[] splVector = vector.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    return splVector;
}
```

Comment: And just for the record,

I could also extendmy Method class to extend Activity or no...?

Comment: @StathisDariskos - I don't think extending Activity would work, unless it was an actual activity of your app. Unless the activity is created by the Android framework, it won't be hooked up to the resources correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call getResources() method on the context .

Pass a context as an argument to the method

just call like `mContext.getResources()`

Answer (score 0):

`getResources()` is a method in Context. As your class no longer extends Context (you were extending Activity earlier, and Activity extends Context) you can no longer access this method.

To be able to call such methods in a non Context class, you need an instance of Context, which you can take in via and store in your constructor. Something like:

```
public class Helper {
    Context mContext;

    public Helper(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // This function reads a txt file is my MATLAB vector and converts it
    // into an Integer[] array for use by the plot function
    public Integer[] convertFiletoIntegerArray(int id) throws NotFoundException, NumberFormatException {

        List<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        InputStream in = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            vector.add(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
        }

        Integer[] splVector = vector.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        return splVector;
    }
}
```

Now use it in your Activity with:

```
Helper helpclass = new Helper(getBaseContext());
helpclass.convertFiletoIntegerArray(YourID);
```

Note that if any of these methods needs to create and show a dialog of any kind, you will need to have a valid (visible) Activity's context.